# WebBrowser issue (add infinite progress in web browser)

Tags: codenameone

It takes a couple of seconds to load an url in webbrowser. Sometimes it takes more time to load. How to add infinite progress like that of connectionRequest in webbrowser?

```
@Override
protected void postWebView(Form f) {
    WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
    if (businessWebsiteUrl != null && !businessWebsiteUrl.equals("")) {
        wb.setURL("http://" + businessWebsiteUrl);
        f.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, wb);
    } else {
    }
    f.revalidate();
}
```

What I did but doesnot work

```
protected void beforeWebView(Form f) {
ip = new InfiniteProgress();
f.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(ip));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's inherently problematic since a browser is effectively a peer component and while we can now paint on top of peers in Android this is still not portable.

Even if it would I'm not sure if it would be a good idea.

Overall you have the following options:

1. Place a progress indicator above/below the browser component
2. Fetch the data separately as HTML with a progress and set the HTML which should be instant
3. Use JavaScript and potentially an `iframe` to indicate progress from within the browser component itself

Comment: Can you explain 2nd and 3rd option more clearly please.

Comment: 2. Means just downloading the HTML and showing it in the browser directly instead of pointing to a URL. 3. Do the progress in JavaScript not in Codename One.

Comment: Since 2016 you can now z-order on top of peer components so you could use an `InteractionDialog` on top of the browser component to indicate progress.